# How can I configure VirtualHost without restarting Apache web server?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have mentioned here apache web server because i am using that one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I just had a look at this page but not sure how relevant its to yours.

[Dynamically Configured Mass Virtual Hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/mass.html)

The basic idea is to replace all of the static  configurations with a mechanism that works them out dynamically. This has a number of advantages:

1. Your configuration file is smaller, so Apache starts more quickly and uses less memory.
2. Adding virtual hosts is simply a matter of creating the appropriate directories in the filesystem and entries in the DNS - **you don't need to reconfigure or restart Apache.**

**UPDATE**

[Adding Virtual Hosts without Restarting Apache](http://www.lionleaf.com/blog/?p=3)

> It turned out that the solution was to
>   use VirtualDocumentRoot instead of
>   just the plain old DocumentRoot
>   setting for a single virtual host. 
>   This allowed specifying the $0
>   variable as part of the value.  So we
>   ended up being able to have
>   “VirtualDocumentRoot /somedir/$1″.

Answer (score 26):

Make any changes to your VirtualHosts, then do

```
apache2ctl configtest
```

To make sure there aren't any outstanding syntax errors, and run this:

```
apache2ctl graceful
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 graceful
```

> The USR1 or graceful signal causes
>   the parent process to advise the
>   children to exit  after their current
>   request (or to exit immediately if
>   they're not serving anything). The 
>   parent re-reads its configuration
>   files and re-opens its log files. As
>   each child dies off  the parent
>   replaces it with a child from the new
>   generation of the configuration, which
>   begins serving new requests
>   immediately.

Basically any existing connections stay intact, so it's not the same as a full restart - this is how I usually do this on production servers with dozens of sites.